# SQL Server Agent Not Scheduling

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running SQL Server Standard (linux) in a docker container and the Agent is not working to any schedule (recurring, one time).

The agent itself works, I have programmed a couple jobs which are completing successfully. However, the jobs do not even start when I activate the schedule meaning there isn't even an error message to review or record in the job activity monitor. Below is my configuration:

[sql server job properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnUML.png)

[image: sql server job schedule]

Comment: That all looks ok.  Is the job itself disabled maybe?

Comment: Define *not working* - what do you see if you open the Job Activity Monitor and view the history of the job?

Comment: @Squillman No the job itself is enabled, I have verified.

Comment: @Stu the job never runs so there is no record in the activity monitor. If I trigger it manually it will show but the intention is to schedule it.

Comment: So you're saying the date/time shown in the *Next run* column elapses and the job never starts, have you checked the server date/time settings are correct?

Comment: @Stu that's correct. the host is in EST and the container is in UTC, which may be part of the issue. However the job has been enabled for long enough that it would have caught the 5 hour delta.

Comment: @Stu timezone was the issue thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the timezone issue by passing the proper environment variable, America/Toronto did not not pass properly, so I used America/New_York.

Comment: When SO allows, please select this as the solution to your question.